# Pagination not working for cpt

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, theme-roots

I'm using this script to catch posts from a custom post type

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
          'post_status' => array('publish', 'future'),
          'post_type' => 'evento',
          'orderby' => 'date',
          'order' => 'DESC',
          'posts_per_page' => 9,
          'paged' => $paged
     );
```

If I set Settings >> Reading >> Blog pages show at most to 6, site return 404 on the second page. If I set to 5, works fine. Why it happens?

I'm using roots theme.

Comment: How many posts you have?

Comment: @Chittaranjan Now, 13.

Comment: What debug errors do you receive with debug set to true in wp-config?

Comment: @PieterGoosen I get no error.